# How to have a submit button outside of a form with jquery .on()

Tags: jquery, html

i want to hide a form and have the submit button visible but outside of the form tags. i understand how to do this with jquery and have made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/5jxbysoL/3/).
The problem i have is that i am using jquery .on() to render certain elements on my page and i can't figure out how to submit the form when using the .on() syntax.

if i put the submit button outside of the form tags on the example below jquery does not submit anything.

My Form

```
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post" style="">
 <input type="hidden" name="name" value="name">
 </form>

   <button type="submit" class=""></button>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', '.results', function(e) {
    var new_data = $(this).closest('div').attr('class') 

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'add_tag.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {

            $('.' + new_data).hide().fadeIn("slow").append('<td>' + response + '</td>');

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that I did this recently was I used a `label` with a `for` and styled it like a button.

```
<form style="display: none" ...>
  ...

  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<label class="button" for="submit">Submit</label>
```

Since clicking the element with the `for` activates the `input` with the corresponding `id`, it works the same way as clicking a submit that's inside of the form. This takes care of your submit problem.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.